# Android Visualizer behavior

Tags: android, audio, visualizer, aubio

I'm trying to use a C library (Aubio) to perform beat detection on some music playing from a `MediaPlayer` in Android. To capture the raw audio data, I'm using a [`Visualizer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html), which sends a byte buffer at regular intervals to a callback function, which in turn sends it to the C library through JNI.

I'm getting inconsistent results (i.e. almost no beats are detected, and the only ones who are are not really consistent with the audio). I've checked multiple times, and, while I can't exactly rule out what I'm doing on my own, I'm wondering how exactly the Android `Visualizer` behaves, since it is not explicit in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html).

- If I set the buffer size using `setCaptureSize`, does that mean that the captured buffer is averaged over the complete audio samples? For instance, if I divide the capture size by 2, will it still represent the same captured *sound*, but with 2 times less *precision* on the time axis?
- Is it the same with the capture rate? For instance, does setting twice the capture size with half the rate yield the same data?
- Are the captures consecutive? To put it another way, if I take too long to process a capture, are the sounds played during the processing ignored when I receive the next capture?

Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the callback function gets the entire audio signal, for instance by counting the frames that get out of it, and the ones that reach the callback.

It would help to be pointed at `Visualizer` documentation.

Comment: It's been a pretty long time since I've worked on that. I'll look into it when I get back to my project ;)